# Different glyphs selection for different language

Tags: html, css, fonts

Could anyone explain to me why when I set the `lang="ar"` the font family selects  `sans-serif` font while when it is `lang="en"` it selects `Open Sans`.

```html
<html lang="ar">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps Open Sans does not include the characters required for that language? In such a case, it will fall back to the next font in line.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks a lot, useful short answer.

please put it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You can sort by language on fonts.google.com

Comment: fix the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's going on is that the [Arabic characters are not supported by Open Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sans#Unicode_coverage). So in both your snippets, Open Sans is not being applied at all, and the browser goes straight to the fallback font.

The reason why the font looks different in both your snippets is because in your first snippet, the browser knows the language is Arabic because of the `lang` tag. It asks the system for the best `sans-serif` fallback font *for Arabic*, and on a Mac this is Geeza Pro Regular.

In your second snippet, the browser thinks the language is English, and asks for the best `sans-serif` fallback font *for English*. On Mac, this is Arial.

Both Geeza Pro and Arial apparently have support for Arabic text, but depending on the actual language, the system chooses one over the other.

Answer (score 11):

Not all fonts contain all characters. Most likely, Open Sans doesn't include the correct characters for that language and so the browser will fall to the next font in line, and so on until looking for system fonts that may have the character you need. Finally, if all else fails, you get "tofu", usually an empty box, a box with an X, or a box containing the hex code of the character.

You can find more information in the official W3C `CSS Fonts Module Level 3` specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-matching-algorithm.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How does setting the lang attribute affect which characters are in the font?

Comment: @Alohci your comment confused me again, your question is valid.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol could you please explain how?.

Comment: Isn't [this mechanism](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why#fonts) involved here (also covered a bit in [MDN's page for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override) `font-language-override`)?

Comment: The language attribute isn't affecting what characters are in the font. Font's can have characters setup for all sorts of different languages, since a lot of different languages use different symbols. So the 'Open Sans' font might not have any characters set for the language 'ar' which would mean that the browser would look at the next font, in this case sans-serif, and prioritize that font if it does have characters for 'ar'. Whether or not the this is the problem I can't say.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn - That looks very much like the explanation. Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The **fallback algorithm** is completely up **to the vendor**, 
so each browser could differ in its own implementation.

What commonly happens?

1. Define your `fontFamily` list: `a, b, c, d`;

This list is priority based, so, the browser will lookup from `l0 => ln`.

2. `glyph lookup step`: The TextEngine tries to draw the text considering the given list and it gracefully fallbacks from `l0` to `ln`.

Because your text `السلام عليكم` cannot be rendered with your first preferred fontFamily, it fallbacks to `any sans-serif`

You can find a more in-depth explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29242255/4099454

Comment: But both fonts have the glyphs inside as you can see at the code snippets. The font changes when the `lang` attribute changes and it sets either Open Sans or sans-serif and [Ilya's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533215/ilya-streltsyn) pretty explains why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons the '-' char of sans-serif was a problem for the arabic language, now all works ^^

```html
<html lang="ar">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="zu">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';">
  السلام عليكم
</body>

</html>
```